# NuxtJS server not starting up on Windows 10

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, windows-10, nuxt.js

I installed `NuxtJS v2.15.3` on my windows 10 system using NPM. When I try to run it using `npm run dev` using the integrated terminal of *VSCode (also VSCodium)*, it just opens the `nuxt.js` file instead of running the server using the file.

I do not have any specific `code` to show here since it is just the default code we have as we run `npm i nuxt`. I found no way to tackle this as the same project ran perfectly on another Ubuntu machine. Any help is appreciated.

Main dependencies list:

- nuxt: 2.15.3
- bootstrap: 4.6.0
- bootstrap-vue: 2.21.2
- express: 4.17.1

Comment: Hi, Is it logging something when you run the server>

Comment: `> my-vue-nuxt@1.0.0 dev C:\test\my-vue-nuxt > nuxt`

@YashMaheshwari nope, just these 2 starting lines and then it just opens the `nuxt.js` file.

Comment: How did you created the project? And what is the content of your `package.json`? Do you have node installed on windows?

Comment: @kissu i just followed the install instructions in the docs. Yes, node `v14.16.0` is installed.